# Our unique visitor numbers are rising, but our page views are not: what can we do?

Tags: discussion, statistics, site-promotion

The Sustainability Stack Exchange is getting established, and we've had some great content posted, like

- [How can I be more energy efficient in an apartment?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/223/48)
- [Which solar power technology has the highest energy return (EROEI)?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1013/48)
- [Meat or fish, which requires more energy to produce?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/832/48).

**But**:

In addition to the super-sekrit mod ninja tools, I use the [Quantcast stats](https://www.quantcast.com/sustainability.stackexchange.com?country=GLOBAL) to keep track of how we're doing, and have noticed that **although our numbers of unique visitors are trending upwards, the number of page views is not**.

[image: good news] *Unique visitors trending upwards*

[image: eeek!] *page views not trending upwards*

I guess that means that although we're getting more people landing, they're bouncing off sooner; that is, the number of pages per unique visitor is trending *downwards*, at about the same rate as the number of unique visitors is trending *upwards*.

As we're something like the hundredth Stack Exchange to go through the Area51 process to beta, I figured this sort of pattern has been seen before, and that people have some ideas about how to change things for the better.

And so, my fellow metarsupials, I ask for your advice. **How can we get our page views trending upwards too?**

Comment: This is more fitting as Area51 discussion.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but [onStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) might also be able to help you here (they are doing marketing and similar). But please ask first on their Meta if they'd accept this question.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kBhuQ.png

Answer (score 7):

It is completely normal for the page views/visitor statistic to decline after the early beta phase. The audience during the early days is very different than in the later phases.

In the early phases there are more users looking at the site as a whole, either they commited from the start, are interested users already active in the SE network or were pointed to the site by some other user. Search engines are not a major traffic source in the very beginning. Later, search engines become the dominant traffic source, and this changes the page views per visitor ratio. If you check other SE sites in Quantcast you'll see that the Visits/Unique ratio starts high and the trends downwards to 1 when the site gets older and more traffic.

I wouldn't worry about this specific statistic at all, as long as the traffic is not decreasing on the whole.